# Корректность фразы "Ему свойственны свои организационно-правовые особенности"

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Ему свойственны свои организационно-правовые особенности" — корректна ли фраза?

Answer (score 1):

Стилистически - не очень. "Свойственны свои" - уже вызывает вопросы. А вот на что менять, сказать без контекста невозможно. Как и то, насколько корректна фраза в остальном.

Answer (score 0):

Без контекста непонятно.